# Vim: how to reflow text in an HTML paragraph

Tags: vim

I'm editing a paragraph in a existing HTML file remotely, and it has proper indentation (by Emacs' `html-mode` standards) and hard line breaks where lines would exceed 80 chars or so. Like this:

```
<body>
  <p>
    Aaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc dd
    eeeeeeeeeeeee ffffffffffffff gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg eee
  <p>
</body>
```

I need to rewrite, say, half of the text in the paragraph, which keeping the style intact. In Emacs, I can edit the text without worrying about indentation and linebreaks, and then press one key combination, <kbd>M-q</kbd>, that would call `fill-paragraph` and put line breaks and indentation in proper places (or I can use this key combination during editing, if I'm feeling extra tidy).

Is there a way to do something similar in Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `:setl textwidth=80`. After editing the text, select the edited lines in visual mode (e.g. `Vjjj`), then re-indent with `=`. Finally, re-establish the selection and re-format: `gvgq`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. If I'm not careful with selection, `gq` pushes several tags together on the same line, but looks like this is the best option anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
:set textwidth=80
```

Will set the line limit to 80. This article explains how to link a HTML tidy program into vim: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanup_your_HTML

Comment: What if it's on a remote machine, one I don't have much access to? Otherwise I would just use Emacs.

Comment: Could you give me the best approximation using Vim's built-in features?